# Assembly language shell sort?

Tags: sorting, assembly, arm, keil

I have been doing an ARM assembly language program and now it is near the end.
However, a shell sort program from C need to be converted into my code so that the last part is complete, but I do not quite understand this part. So I want to post my code here and ask you guys for some guidance on shell sort in **ARM assembly language**

Also any suggestions for my code are appreciated.

```
    AREA ShellSort, CODE, READONLY

destinationArray EQU 0x40000000

    ENTRY

    LDR    r1,=sourceArray
    LDR    r0,=destinationArray
    MOV     r2, #0              ; pointer to the original
    MOV     r3, #0              ; pointer to the destination array
    MOV     r4, #19             ; loop counter (20 elemenets so 0-19 counts as 18)
    MOV     r5, #1              ; size of copyArray

    LDR     r3, [r1], #1        ; copy element
    STR     r3, [r0]    

    BL     copyArray
    LDR    r0,=sourceArray
    MOV    r1,#arraySize
    BL     shellSort

stop    B         stop


val
    SUB    r3,#1              ;Address of source array passed in R0
    LDR    r3, [r0], #1       ;Address of destination array passed in R1
    LDR    r0, =destinationArray                      ;Number of array elements pass



copyArray

    STR r3, [r0]
    ADD     r5, #1
    MOV     r6, r5
    CMP     r4, #0
    BNE     val
    MOV PC,LR    ;Return to calling subroutine      

shellSort

    MOV PC,LR  ;Return to calling subroutine


arraySize       EQU 20
sourceArray     DCD -9,23,-100,675,2,98,13,-4,1000,23,5,234,45,67,12,-2,54,2,17,99

    END
```

Comment: Understand the algorithm, implement it in ASM, simples. What do you actually want to know? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I mean shell sort seems like need nested loops right? A while loop and a for loop to implement is what I have seen, that's something that I got stuck.

Comment: @enhzflep also the flags in the sorting algorithm is another part that I don't know how to actually convert into the assembly language...

Comment: I can't help you with ShellSort, I've never bothered to implement it.  When you say you don't know how to convert it into assembly language, I'm not quite sure what to make of this. You'd need a reason to be doing this - it's seems likely to be either a homework assignment or an ill-assigned task to someone not equipped to perform it. If you merely want an assembly listing and dont care for the understanding, you can get an output from GCC if you write the function in C and compile with the -S option, which will leave you with the assembly listing. Failing that, you need to study hard

Comment: Since shell sort is really like some ancient thing so I was really not able to deal with it so that's why that I asked for help. But thanks for the tip tho, the GCC stuff I got is a complete mess. But will definitely try from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770440/why-does-this-program-take-exponentially-longer-with-sizes-of-greater-than-50.   You (Bbz) can delete this question, if it superseeded or if you think it will not be useful to others.  Maybe this is the same class?

Comment: How about using 'Linux quicksort'? See second answer on question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770440/why-does-this-program-take-exponentially-longer-with-sizes-of-greater-than-50[/link].

Answer (score 0):

My environment is different from your. I have redone your code to fit my test system. I have searched for a good arm assembly sort and have not found any. A bubble sort is good for short sorts. I have found that 'Linux qsort' is very good and have inserted it in your program. My changes are in lower case and you may be able to readjust it to fit your environment.

```
.data

.equ arraySize, 20

sourceArray:
    .word   -9,23,-100,675,2,98,13,-4,1000,23,5,234,45,67,12,-2,54,2,17,99

.equ numbytes, (arraySize * 4)
destinationArray:       @ Memory is 1 byte and an integer is 4 bytes
    .skip  numbytes     @   (1 word) on my Raspbian Jessie RPi3,
                        @   adjust for your environment.
.balign 4
format:
    .asciz " %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d  %4d\n"

.balign 4
fmt:
    .asciz "\n"

.text

.global main
main:
@   ENTRY

    push    {r4-r10, lr}        @ save registers and return value
    LDR     r1, =sourceArray
    LDR     r0, =destinationArray
    MOV     r2, #0              @ pointer to the original
    MOV     r3, #0              @ pointer to the destination array
    MOV     r4, #19             @ loop counter (20 elemenets so 0-19 counts as 18)
    MOV     r5, #1              @ size of copyArray

@   LDR     r3, [r1], #1        @ copy element
@   STR     r3, [r0]    

    BL     copyArray
    LDR    r0, =sourceArray
@   MOV    r1, #arraySize
    ldr    r1, =arraySize
    BL     shellSort

stop:
@   B      stop
    mov    r0,  #0
    pop    {r4-r10, lr}        @ restore registers and return to caller
    bx     lr


val:
    SUB    r3,#1              @Address of source array passed in R0
    LDR    r3, [r0], #1       @Address of destination array passed in R1
    LDR    r0, =destinationArray          @Number of array elements pass



copyArray:
    ldr     r3, [r1], #4      @ index source, int takes 4 bytes
@   STR     r3, [r0]
    str     r3, [r0], #4      @ index destination
    ADD     r5, #1
    MOV     r6, r5
    subs    r4, #1            @ counter--
    bgt     copyArray         @ continue copying array
@   CMP     r4, #0
@   BNE     val
    MOV     PC, LR    @Return to calling subroutine      

shellSort:

@   MOV     PC,LR  @Return to calling subroutine


@ arraySize       EQU 20
@ sourceArray     DCD -9,23,-100,675,2,98,13,-4,1000,23,5,234,45,67,12,-2,54,2,17,99

@   END                                                                 

@ ---- All below this line is added for qsort (not shellsort) ----

@ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm
@
@ http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html
@
@ void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
@            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
@
@      qsort(r0 =array, r1 =numelements, r2 = 4 bytes,
@            r0=(r3 =cmpfunc){ r0=[r0] - r1=[r1] })

qsort_setup:
    push  {r0-r12, lr}            @ save environment
    ldr   r0,  =destinationArray  @ sorting destinationArray
    ldr   r1,  =arraySize         @ size of array elements
    mov   r2,  #4                 @ size of integer
    ldr   r3,  =cmpfunc           @ compare function for int
    bl    qsort                   @ Linux OS build in sort 

    b     print_sourceArray

cmpfunc:                          @ This work per specs above
    ldr   r0,  [r0]
    ldr   r1,  [r1]
    sub   r0,  r0, r1
    mov   pc,  lr

print_sourceArray:
    ldr   r0,  =fmt
    bl    printf
    ldr   r0,  =sourceArray
    bl    prt_half_array
    ldr   r0,  =sourceArray
    ldr   r1,  =numbytes
    add   r0,  r1, lsr #1
    bl    prt_half_array


print_destinationArray:
    ldr   r0,  =fmt
    bl    printf
    ldr   r0,  =destinationArray
    bl    prt_half_array
    ldr   r0,  =destinationArray
    ldr   r1,  =numbytes
    add   r0,  r1, lsr #1
    bl    prt_half_array
    ldr   r0,  =fmt
    bl    printf

    pop   {r0-r12, lr}            @ restore enviroment
    mov   pc, lr                  @ return

prt_half_array:
    push  {r0, lr}
    ldm   r0,  {r1-r10}
    ldr   r0,  =format
    push  {r4-r10}
    bl    printf
    add   sp,  #28
    pop   {r0, pc}
.end
```