# Why does this program take exponentially longer with sizes of greater than 50?

Tags: assembly, arm

So I'm writing an ARM assembly quicksort method for class.  I have the understanding down for the most part, other than the complexity is not making sense.

We're comparing it to another bubble sort method we made and it performs better for examples with 1 argument and 10 arguments.  However I can't even compare the 100 argument test because it takes too long...I cant get it to do 75 even, but 50 is done in a few seconds.

This is what I have,

```
qsort:  @ Takes three parameters:
    @   a:     Pointer to base of array a to be sorted (arrives in r0)
    @   n:  number of elements in the array (arrives in r1)

    stmfd   sp!, {r4, r6, lr}     @ Save r4 and r6 for caller
    mov     r6, r1                @ r6 <- right
    mov r2, #0                    @ r2 <- left
qsort_tailcall_entry:
    sub     r7, r6, r2            @ If right - left <= 1 (already sorted),
    cmp     r7, #1
    ldmlefd sp!, {r4, r6, pc}     @ Return, restoring r4 and r6
    ldr     r7, [r0, r2, asl #2]  @ r7 <- a[left], gets pivot element
    add     r1, r2, #1            @ l <- left + 1
    mov     r4, r6                @ r <- right
partition_loop:
    ldr     r3, [r0, r1, asl #2]  @ r3 <- a[l]
    cmp     r3, r7                @ If a[l] <= pivot_element,
    addle   r1, r1, #1            @ ... increment l, and
    ble     partition_test        @ ... continue to next iteration.
    sub     r4, r4, #1            @ Otherwise, decrement r,
    ldr     r8, [r0, r4, asl #2]  @ ... and swap a[l] and a[r].
    str     r8, [r0, r1, asl #2]
    str     r3, [r0, r4, asl #2]
partition_test:
    cmp     r1, r4                @ If l < r,
    blt     partition_loop        @ ... continue iterating.
partition_finish:
    sub     r1, r1, #1            @ Decrement l
    ldr     r3, [r0, r1, asl #2]  @ Swap a[l] and pivot
    str     r3, [r0, r2, asl #2]
    str     r7, [r0, r1, asl #2]
    bl      qsort                 @ Call self recursively on left part,
                                  @  with args a (r0), left (r2), r (r2),
                                  @  also preserves r4 and r6
    mov     r2, r4
    b       qsort_tailcall_entry  @ Tail-call self on right part,
                                  @  with args a (r0), l (r2), right (r6)
```

Can anyone help me understand why in the world it's taking THIS long and growing exponentially?  What could I do to fix it?

Comment: At least it's well commented, we don't see that around here much (+1) ... how about you single step it for a small array (like 3 items) and see if it does the expected things?

Comment: What are you running it on, and how much memory does it have available? "Recursive algorithm goes funny with sufficiently large data" often means you've blown the stack.

Comment: Will do.  My inspiration for the way this is setup came from many online sources so I tried to keep track of where I was with the comments.  EDIT: Yea I'm running it on a rasp pi so that may be the issue.

Comment: Come on, for 100 elements? RPi should be more than enough for that...

Comment: I think my implementation is just jank honestly lol.  I'll try to just refactor it all or start from scratch w/o recursion.

Comment: Still early morning for me but, worst thing you can get with quicksort is choosing first element as pivot and trying to sort an already sorted array. For performance comparison I would also write a C version and see how that performs and see if problem is in arm implementation which doesn't look obviously bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have not studied your logic, but have added some debug script to your program that may help you. The wrapper is a stand alone program.

```
/* qsort1.s */

@ ---- Added ----
.data

tstdat:
    .word 9, 9, 9, 9, 9

array:
    .word 3, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 5, 4
len:
    .word ((len - array) /4)

.balign 4
format:
    .asciz " %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  %2d  |  %2d  %2d  %2d\n"


.text

.global main

Print:
    push  {r0-v7, lr}
    mrs   v7,  cpsr
    push  {v7, v8}
    push  {r2, r6, r7}
    ldr   r7,  =array
    ldm   r7,  {r1-r9}
    push  {r4-r9}
    ldr   r0,  =format
    bl    printf
    add   sp,  #36
    pop   {v7, v8}
    msr   cpsr_f, v7
    pop   {r0-v7, pc}

main:

    ldr     r0,  =array
    ldr     r1,  =len
    ldr     r1,  [r1]

    push    {r3-r11, lr}
    bl      Print
    bl      qsort
    bl      Print
    pop     {r3-r11, pc}

@ ---------------------------

qsort:  @ Takes three parameters:
    @   a:     Pointer to base of array a to be sorted (arrives in r0)
    @   n:  number of elements in the array (arrives in r1)

    stmfd   sp!, {r4, r6, lr}     @ Save r4 and r6 for caller
    mov     r6, r1                @ r6 <- right
    mov     r2, #0                @ r2 <- left
qsort_tailcall_entry:
    sub     r7, r6, r2            @ If right - left <= 1 (already sorted),
@   bl      Print                @ <---- Added
    cmp     r7, #1
    ldmlefd sp!, {r4, r6, pc}     @ Return, restoring r4 and r6
    ldr     r7, [r0, r2, asl #2]  @ r7 <- a[left], gets pivot element
    add     r1, r2, #1            @ l <- left + 1
    mov     r4, r6                @ r <- right
partition_loop:
    ldr     r3, [r0, r1, asl #2]  @ r3 <- a[l]
    cmp     r3, r7                @ If a[l] <= pivot_element,
    addle   r1, r1, #1            @ ... increment l, and
    ble     partition_test        @ ... continue to next iteration.
    sub     r4, r4, #1            @ Otherwise, decrement r,
    ldr     r8, [r0, r4, asl #2]  @ ... and swap a[l] and a[r].
    str     r8, [r0, r1, asl #2]
    str     r3, [r0, r4, asl #2]
    bl      Print                @ <---- Added
partition_test:
    cmp     r1, r4                @ If l < r,
    blt     partition_loop        @ ... continue iterating.
partition_finish:
    sub     r1, r1, #1            @ Decrement l
    ldr     r3, [r0, r1, asl #2]  @ Swap a[l] and pivot
    str     r3, [r0, r2, asl #2]
    str     r7, [r0, r1, asl #2]
    bl      qsort                 @ Call self recursively on left part,
                                  @  with args a (r0), left (r2), r (r2),
                                  @  also preserves r4 and r6
    mov     r2, r4
    b       qsort_tailcall_entry  @ Tail-call self on right part,
                                  @  with args a (r0), l (r2), right (r6)
```

Here is the start of the output. The left side is the array to be sorted and the right side is r2, r6 and r7. This array is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Quicksort-diagram.svg).

```
pi@RPi:~/pgm $ mym qsort1
as -o qsort1.o qsort1.s
gcc -o qsort1 qsort1.o

./qsort1; echo $?
  3   7   8   5   2   1   9   5   4  |  2126935836  66296   0 (before pgm)
  3   4   8   5   2   1   9   5   7  |   0   9   3
  3   5   8   5   2   1   9   4   7  |   0   9   3
  3   9   8   5   2   1   5   4   7  |   0   9   3
  3   1   8   5   2   9   5   4   7  |   0   9   3
  3   1   2   5   8   9   5   4   7  |   0   9   3    
 ...
 (  array to be sorted             )    r2   r4  r7
```

Comment: you don't need to assemble "manually" if you're linking with gcc.  Just `gcc -o qsort1 qsort1.S`.  (And use `.S` for your hand-written asm source even if you don't need the C preprocessor, because `.s` can get clobbered with no warning by compilers and disassemblers.)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what the columns were that you're printing, instead of expecting people to read your uncommented code.

Comment: @Peter Cordes. Thank you for your suggestions. I am okay with the way that I assemble and link programs.

Answer (score 0):

To fix quicksort for getting extra long, a fix would be to use 'Linux qsort' to sort numbers.

```
@ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm
@
@ http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html
@
@ void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
@            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
@
@      qsort(r0 =array, r1 =numelements, r2 = 4 bytes,
@            r0=(r3 =cmpfunc){ r0=[r0] - r1=[r1] })

cmpfunc:
    ldr   r0,  [r0]
    ldr   r1,  [r1]
    sub   r0,  r0, r1
    mov   pc,  lr

qsort_setup:
    ldr   r0,  =array
    ldr   r1,  =numbytes
    lsr   r1,  #2
    mov   r2,  #4
    ldr   r3,  =cmpfunc

    bl    qsort
```

A complete demo program using urandom numbers.

```
/* qsort14.s */

.data

@ See /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/unistd.h
@ See /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/fcntl-linux.h

    .equ create,     8
         .equ Mode, 0644       @ -rw-r--r--
    .equ open,       5
         .equ Rd,   00
         .equ Wr,   01
         .equ RdWr, 02
         .equ Apnd, 02000
    .equ read,       3
    .equ write,      4
    .equ close,      6
    .equ sync,       36
    .equ exit,       1
    .equ sfile,      187

    .equ numbytes,  (64 * 4)     @ Has to be multiples
@   .equ numbytes,  (128 * 4)    @  of 8 times 4.
@   .equ numbytes,  (512 * 4) 

.balign 4
array: .skip numbytes

.balign 4
dir_file:
    .asciz "/dev/urandom"

.balign 4
Open:
    .word dir_file, RdWr | Apnd, open

.balign 4
Read:
    .word array, numbytes, read

.balign 4
hex3ff:
    .word 0x3ff

.balign 4
format:
    .asciz " %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u  %4u\n"

.balign 4
fmt:
    .asciz "\n"

@ ---------------------------

.text

.global main

Prt_arr:
    push  {r0-r12, lr}
    mrs   r12,  cpsr
    push  {r11, r12}
    mov   r0,  #0xa
    bl    putchar
    ldr   r12, =numbytes
    lsr   r12, #5
    mov   r11, #0
endprt:
    ldr   r0,  =array
    add   r0,  r11
    ldm   r0,  {r1-r8}
    push  {r4-r12}
    ldr   r0,  =format
    bl    printf
    pop   {r4-r12}
    add   r11, #32
    subs  r12, #1
    bne   endprt
    pop   {r11, r12}
    msr   cpsr_f, r12
    pop   {r0-r12, lr}
    mov   pc, lr

@ ---- Program starts here ----
@ ---- Read random numbers ----

main:
    push  {r4-r12, lr}

    ldr   r3, =Open            @ load address
    ldm   r3, {r0, r1, r7}     @ load registers
    svc   #0                   @ OS opens urandom file
    mov   r4, r0               @ save fd in r4

    ldr   r3, =Read            @ load address
    ldm   r3, {r1, r2, r7}     @ load registers
    svc   #0                   @ OS reads urandom file

    mov   r0, r4               @ move fd in r0
    mov   r7, #close           @ num for close
    svc   #0                   @ OS closes urandom file

@ ---- Fix array so numbers are 999 or less ----

    ldr   r10, =array
    ldr   r1,  =numbytes
    sub   r1,  #4
    ldr   r2,  =hex3ff
    ldr   r2,  [r2]
fix:
    ldr   r0,  [r10, r1]
    and   r0,  r2
    cmp   r0,  #1000
    subge r0,  #1000
    lslge r0,  r0, #5
    str   r0,  [r10, r1]
    subs  r1,  #4
    bpl   fix

@ ---- Print unsorted array ----

    bl    Prt_arr
    b     qsort_setup

@ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm
@
@ http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html
@
@ void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
@            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
@
@      qsort(r0 =array, r1 =numelements, r2 = 4 bytes,
@            r0=(r3 =cmpfunc){ r0=[r0] - r1=[r1] })

cmpfunc:
    ldr   r0,  [r0]
    ldr   r1,  [r1]
    sub   r0,  r0, r1
    mov   pc,  lr

qsort_setup:
    ldr   r0,  =array
    ldr   r1,  =numbytes
    lsr   r1,  #2
    mov   r2,  #4
    ldr   r3,  =cmpfunc

    bl    qsort

End:
    bl    Prt_arr
    mov   r0,  #0xa
    bl    putchar

    pop    {r4-r12, lr}
    bx     lr

.end
```